# PHP: Https Curl using Proxy

Tags: php, curl, https, proxy

i'm trying to make a curl request to a https based url. But seems nothing returned back..
I tested with many proxy that worked for non https.

```
$att = "cookie.txt";
$ip = "121.14.138.56:81";
$curl = curl_init("https://www.att.com");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROXY, $ip);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $att);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $att);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.94 Safari/537.36"); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 50);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$reply = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
echo $reply;
```

Comment: Before you do `curl_close($curl);`, you could print all relevant informations to debug `var_dump(curl_getinfo($curl));`.

Comment: I only get "boolean false" for https links, for http links is ok.

Comment: Check if your php installation is compiled with openssl (`phpinfo()`).

Comment: yes "OpenSSL 0.9.8y 5 Feb 2013" installed

Answer (score 0):

Seems this code is working. Note: only some proxy support https..

```
$proxy = "205.221.221.111:8080";
$curl = curl_init("https://www.att.com");
if (isset($proxy)) {curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);}
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $att);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $att);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.94 Safari/537.36"); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'cookie.txt'); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$reply = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
var_dump(curl_getinfo($curl));
echo $reply;
```